# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: infowindow is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, scope

I've been struggling with this issue for sometime now and have done some proper research here on stackoverflow and online but have not figured out how to approach and solve this problem.

The issue I am having is that the variable 'infowindow' is undefined. I think I have focused it down to a scoping issue but am having a difficult time finding a solution. The error message is targeting this part of the source code:

```
    //Remove default infowindow styling
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
```

with the error message 'Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: infowindow is not defined at initMap'

I assume I have to define the variable 'infowindow' in the global scope, or at least outside of the function scope but my attempts have only broken the code itself. I notice that 'infoWindow'(note: Capital W) has been defined in the prior function but am not sure where to place the variable declaration? What should my approach be to this problem?

```
   var map;
     function initMap() {
       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: {lat: 37.791992, lng: -122.344085},
          zoom: 12,
      //Google maps styling
      styles: [
        {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#242f3e'}]},
        {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]},
        {
          featureType: 'administrative.locality',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#263c3f'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'poi.park',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#6b9a76'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#38414e'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#212a37'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#9ca5b3'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#746855'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#1f2835'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'road.highway',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#f3d19c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#2f3948'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'transit.station',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#d59563'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'geometry',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
          stylers: [{color: '#515c6d'}]
        },
        {
          featureType: 'water',
          elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
          stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
        }
      ]
    });

    //Array of markers
    var markers = [
    {
      coord: {lat:37.791182, lng:-122.198108},
      content: '<img src ="Projects/Public_Art_Project/imgs/IMG_8683.jpg"> 
       <br> <p> MacArthur @ Patterson <br> "A Bear Shaped Hole" <br> 
        Artist: Roger Peet and Rush Santos</p>'

     },
     ];

    //loop through markers
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
      addMarker(markers[i]);
    }

  function addMarker(props){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position:props.coord,
       map: map,
       icon:'/Projects/Public_Art_Project/imgs/markerSprayCan.svg'
  });

    //check content
    if (props.content) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function(){
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
          }
            }
      //Remove default infowindow styling
    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

        var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

        var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

        iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'background' : 
         '#252525'});

        var iwmain = iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)');

        iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

        var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

           });


             };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you need to add the `domready` event listener to each of **your** InfoWindows.  Since you have a unique `infoWindow` for each marker, you need to add it to each:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: props.content
});
//Remove default infowindow styling
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
  var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
  var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();
  iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({
    'background': '#252525'
  });
  var iwmain = iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)');
  iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({
    'display': 'none'
  });
  var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();
});
```

**Note:**  I don't recommend modifying the default google.maps.InfoWindow this way, it will break when Google changes the InfoWindow (which it looks like it has).  Better to use a third party replacement for the InfoWindow (like InfoBubble or InfoBox).

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1xegu3n2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.791182,
      lng: -122.198108
    },
    zoom: 11,
  });

  //Array of markers
  var markers = [{
    coord: {
      lat: 37.791182,
      lng: -122.198108
    },
    content: '<img src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" style="height:100px;"><br><p>MacArthur @ Patterson<br>"A Bear Shaped Hole"<br>Artist: Roger Peet and Rush Santos</p>'
  }, {
    coord: {
      lat: 37.7,
      lng: -122.1
    },
    content: '<img src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" style="height:100px;"><br><p>MacArthur @ Patterson<br>"A Bear Shaped Hole"<br>Artist: Roger Peet and Rush Santos</p>'
  }, ];

  //loop through markers
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers[i]);
  }

  function addMarker(props) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: props.coord,
      map: map,
    });

    //check content
    if (props.content) {
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: props.content
      });
      //Remove default infowindow styling
      google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
        var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
        var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();
        iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({
          'background': '#252525'
        });
        var iwmain = iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)');
        iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({
          'display': 'none'
        });
        var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
  }
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```